# How to create single page application in liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, single-page-application, liferay-7

Can anyone share some detailed info on how to create a Single Page Application (SPA) in Liferay 7 using SennaJS.
I could't found any documentation on How to create SPA in Liferay 7.

Comment: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/automatic-single-page-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the portlet you are going to create and deploy with Liferay SDK/Workspace OR any compatible liferay plugin it will be SPA by default.
No need to do any coding on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

It comes by default, except if you unset the following property:

javascript.single.page.application.enabled=true

BTW, it is rather annoying in dev instances, as it takes a while to load pages in the first access, sometimes you even need to reload the page. Also, be aware, in some **especial** cases, some applications might break, normally due to code that counts with page reloads to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

you can even create it in 6.2 by using the following code.

```
// initializing senna 
                 var app = new senna.App();
                 // Set links selector for navigations
                 app.setLinkSelector(".senna-link");
                 // set basic path of liferay site
                 app.setBasePath('/web/spa-demo/');
                 // Id of DOM element which will be replaced from
                 // next page request
                 // using content div - default in liferay theme
                 app.addSurfaces('content');
                 // define routes for all the navigation links
                 // route link = Base path + page link
                 app.addRoutes([
                     new senna.Route('home', senna.HtmlScreen),
                     new senna.Route('second', senna.HtmlScreen),
                     new senna.Route('third', senna.HtmlScreen),
                 ]);
```

Thing which you need to take care of, if it is SPA, then all the events need to be bound first i.e. delegate as there is not going to be page refresh.

i.e things like document.getReady is only going to be called once.